# How to check syslogs in a Docker container? (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, docker, logging, containers

I have a `Docker` container running our application. For some reason, our logs aren't reaching the Splunk Forwarder and thus not reaching Splunk, so I'm trying to see where the logs are going on the container. I've tried opening the `Docker Desktop` `CLI` for that container, and running commands like `var/log/syslog` , but it says `command not found`. I've been told to try and remote into my dev container and see if any logs run in there, but I'm unsure if I'm going about this the right way (`Docker Desktop CLI` and attempting to run commands to get `syslogs` to show up while I'm using the app).

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if I'm getting any of these concepts wrong? Perhaps the CLI button I'm clicking isn't the way to view these logs?

[image]

Comment: Containers should log to stdout/stderr, and then you'll see the container logs in places like `docker logs`.

Comment: Looking at how splunk docker setup works (at least the Light version of it), I anticipate it is going to be rather difficult without knowing how the whole thing was setup in your case, i.e. what are other containers, the forwarder, the logging driver etc...